# Entity Framework: what do I do with edmgen.exe's output?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm forced to use a legacy SQL Server 2000 database for an EF-based app I am writing. The tables already exist, so I need to generate the `Entities` layer. I can do this in VS2010 using MySQL and recent versions of SQL Server, but not 2000.

To get around this, I followed some tutorials that explain how to generate `csl`, `msdl` and `ssdl` files using `edmgen.exe`.

That works fine. I now have those files in e.g. `c:\temp`.

Please can someone tell me what to do with these files? I want to Entity Framework-ify a simple console application that I have written. Can I somehow create an 'ADO.NET Entity Data Model' from these files so I end up with what I would have if I had used VS2010 all along?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working, here is what I did

1) Use edmgen.exe to generate the files mentioned in my question

```
"C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\edmgen.exe" /mode:fullgeneration /c:"Data Source=<your_server_here>; Initial Catalog=<your_catalog_here>; UID=<username>;PWD=<password>" /project:<vs2010_project_name> /entitycontainer:<project_name>Entities /namespace:<project_name>Model /language:CSharpEntityFramework
```

2) Follow these instructions "How To: use your existing CSDL/MSL/SSDL files in the Entity Designer CTP2" - its actually for VS2008 but it worked for me too.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsimmons/archive/2007/12/07/how-to-use-your-existing-csdl-msl-ssdl-files-in-the-entity-designer-ctp2.aspx

3) I had a further problem in that my legacy db had no primary keys so I followed these instructions which also worked

http://pratapreddypilaka.blogspot.in/2012/04/entity-framework-adding-datatable-with.html

Answer (score 0):

These files are referenced in [EF's connection string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx) and EF use them at runtime to build a mapping but it can still not work because SQL Server 2000 is not supported by EF (at least EF 4.0 and newer). EF can generate SQL not supported by SQL Server 2000 and you will get exceptions at runtime.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav. However, a colleague wrote another EF app that communicates to the same database (he has now left unfortunately). His app works. However, I know that he DID have some problems because of the incompatibility you mention. He managed to solve them though and get it working. In his notes, he mentioned that he used edmgen.exe, which I why I have tried to use it in the same way. I think I am nearly there with the csl, msdl and ssdl files. I just need to know how to 'import' them into my project in VS2010. Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: If you need to import them you will just use Add Existing Item as with any other file and you will set them to be copied to output directory. You will also use them in connection string to database as mentioned in the link. You will not get designer support from these files.

Comment: Yes, I realise that the designer doesn't support doing it this way (hence using edmgen.exe) but unfortunately I don't have a choice about using SQL 2000, so I have to try and make it work. I will give your suggestion a try and report back. Thanks for your help - I  am completely new to EF, so any help I can get with this is really appreciated!